# Help identifying species of vegetable garden pest

Tags: vegetables, pests, herbs, peppers

I am having trouble determining what type of pest has invaded my vegetable garden. It has started with the bok choy and is working its way toward the peppers and herbs. Please advise.

[image: vegetable garden invader]